# Find the minimal polynomial of $x^{1/2}+x^{1/3}$ the field of real rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, minimal-polynomials

> Let $E$ be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $h(x)$ be the algebraic function $h(x)=x^{1/2}+x^{1/3}$. Find the minimal polynomial $P(T) \in E[T]$ of $h$ over $E$. (Hint: You need to eliminate radicals from the equation. Start by simplifying $(h-x^{1/2})^3$.)

Simplifying $(h-x^{1/2})^3$:

$(h-x^{1/2})^3= h^3 -3h^2x^{1/2}+3hx-x^{3/2}$

Now we plug in $x^{1/2}+x^{1/3}$ for all h:

$x+x^{3/2}+3x^{4/3}+3x^{7/6}-3(x+2x^{5/6}+x^{2/3})x^{1/2}+3(x^{1/2}+x^{1/3})-x^{3/2}=$

$x+x^{3/2}+3x^{4/3}+3x^{7/6}-3(x^{3/2}-6x^{4/3}-3x^{7/6})+3x^{3/2}+3x^{4/3}$

$x+x^{3/2}+3x^{4/3}+3x^{7/6}-3x^{3/2}-6x^{4/3}-3x^{7/6}+3x^{3/2}+3x^{4/3}-x^{3/2}=x$

So all radicals are eliminated.

Next, $(h-x^{1/2})^3-x=0$

$h^3-3hx^{1/2}+3hx-x^{3/2}-x=0$

$h^3+3hx-x=x^{1/2}(3h^2+x)$

$(h^3+3hx-x)/(3h^2+x)=x^{1/2}$ substituting for x

$(x^3+3x^2-x)/(3x^2+x)=x^{1/2}$

$(x^2+3x-1)/(3x+1)=x^{1/2}$

$(x^2+3x-1)^2/(3x+1)^2-x=0$

I'm not really sure where this leaves me with respect to finding the minimal polynomial. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $$h^3-3hx^{1/2}+3hx-x^{3/2}-x=0$$ (I didn't check all your steps up to this point. I'll assume they were correct.) Rewrite as $$h^3+(3h-1)x=(3h+x)x^{1/2}$$ and square both sides to get an equation for $h$ (with coefficients in $E$).

Comment: ok, thank you!!

Comment: If this answer meets your needs, you have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: sorry, I forgot!